# Is my JSON API doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This seems to me like some fairly simple Jquery that should be retrieving a JSON object that I'm after

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.json",
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(results) {
    console.log(results);
    }
});
```

Whether I dynamically generate this JSON object or use a static document, the above code returns squat. Here's what the JSON object looks like:

```
{urls:['/ants/','/brick-report/','/the-pollution-intervention/','/barclay/','/broken-advertising/','/aldat-n-densom/','/thisisart/','/there-she-goes-again/']}
```

It's nothing more that a list of urls in an array. I cannot retrieve it using the above ajax code OR with $.getJSON. HALP!

(For clarity, I've edited this to show that the json file and the web page with the Jquery request are in the same directory.)

Comment: Is `http://mydomain.com/json/` not the same domain as where the JavaScript file is loaded from?

Comment: that is not valid json formatting, http://jsonlint.com and I believe it has to be dataType not datatype

Comment: What error you getting

Comment: They are indeed coming from the same domain--same folder for this experiment! My big problem is I could do something with an error--there is none. Another baffling aspect of this; in the developer tools in the file, test.json is listed as a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid Json

```
{
"urls": [
    "/ants/",
    "/brick-report/",
    "/the-pollution-intervention/",
    "/barclay/",
    "/broken-advertising/",
    "/aldat-n-densom/",
    "/thisisart/",
    "/there-she-goes-again/"
 ]
}
```

Comment: OK. It looks like the carriage returns matter. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @ruzel No, not the carriage returns, notice urls => "urls"

Comment: @ruzel valid json do not have newlines or carriage returns, those must be escaped, ie `\n`

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, I removed the carriage returns but retained the quotes around *urls* and it still works fine. Thanks. That additionally solves my next problem, too—delivering JSON with Twig.

Answer (score 0):

You are not only using invalid json, you are also using escape character in wrong way.

1. wrap double quote in key
2. replace to correct escape characeter `\"` instead of `'/`
3. replace all single quotes to double quotes

Here's the correct the json

```
{\"urls\":[\"ants\",\"brick-report\",\"the-pollution-intervention\",\"barclay\",\"broken-advertising\",\"aldat-n-densom\",\"thisisart\",\"there-she-goes-again\"]}
```

Comment: and double quotes around the key names